# Android: Inject fake camera preview for testing purpose

Tags: android, android-camera, android-testing

I am writing some black-box, acceptance tests that run on a physical android device. The application under test (AUT) relies on the camera's preview. Specifically, it uses the `setOneShotPreviewCallback` method of the `android.hardware.Camera` class. I am looking for a way to inject a fake preview picture to test the app's behavior.

I thought I could fool the Camera object by having the test code call the AUT's `PreviewCallback` object, but unfortunately, the instance variable `mPreviewCallback` is private to the Camera object and thus my test code has no way to get a reference to the `PreviewCallback` object.

Another way I thought about was to send a `Message` to the Camera's `EventHandler`, but again the field `mEventHandler` is private, so the test code has no way to get a reference to the Handler.

Comment: I think this suggestion might break your physical device rule but maybe running on genymotion can achieve the trick you desire. http://www.genymotion.com/features/

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: @Machinarius: I have followed your suggestion and have installed genymotion. Although it is a fine piece of software, I could not find a way to programmatically inject an image in the camera's preview stream. It seems the only action genymotions allows is to connect my physical webcam's stream to the simulated camera. Have I overlooked something?

Comment: @Alex My device is not (yet) rooted, but I am ready to do it if it solves my problem.

Comment: @Machinarius With some driver trickery you could trick genymotion into feeding android the image you want. That highly depends on the OS you want to run this on though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android mock Camera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18572130/android-mock-camera)

Answer (score 1):

Please see [Android mock Camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18572130/android-mock-camera) and [How to mock a picture in Android Emulator Camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165618/how-to-mock-a-picture-in-android-emulator-camera?rq=1) Both methods don't need rooted device, but require a change of the application. I believe you can make the necessary modification even if you don't have access to the source code, by decompiling the dex.

Comment: The first question (Android mock Camera) suggests using Mockito to mock the Camera class. Yet, [the mockito offical doc](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html) states that "Mockito doesn't mock final methods". Most Camera's methods being final, it seems mocking Camera is not an option.

Comment: The final methods like [setOneShotPreviewCallback()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setOneShotPreviewCallback(android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback)) are only thin wrappers around native methods. You can create the mock Camera class that will load an alternative native library to implement this method.